# Why does putting {''} crash React's rendering?

Tags: reactjs

I recently tried making a component where I had an empty string inside of the curly brackets in the render function. When I tried rendering it, nothing showed up. Anyone know the reason?

Here's an example. Remove line 22 to see the before and after.
http://jsfiddle.net/tb5p9gpk/113/

`Cause of the problem: {''}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `{' '}` is outside the containing `<div></div>`

```
render: function() {
    return (
        <div> /* containing div */
            <HashTagInput onUpdate={this.onUpdate} hashtag={this.state.hashtag}  />
            <HashTagCount hashtag={this.state.hashtag} />
        </div>
        {' '} /* outside the containing div */
    )
}
```

form the react docs **When called, it should examine this.props and this.state and return a *single child element*.**